# How to append to existing URL in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So my route config look like following

```
export const tenantRoute: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'tenant',
        component: TenantComponent,
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'tenant.home.title'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: TenantDetailComponent,
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                    pageTitle: 'tenant.home.title'
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'dataconfiguration/:id',
                        component: DataConfigurationDetailComponent,
                        data: {
                            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                            pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

So once i am at this point `[routerLink]="['../tenant', tenant.id ]`

now what should be my routerLink should look like for `DataConfigurationDetailComponent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
[routerLink]="['../tenant', tenant.id, 'dataconfiguration', id ]
```